# Google sheets query to get unique client IDs and order by sales value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, unique

I'm trying to get a list of unique client IDs and sorted in a desc order based on sales value in a different column.
My data:
Client ID Column A
Sales Value Column B

Thank you for your help.

I managed to get a unique list of clients eliminating where Sales Value is blank, but this returns 2 columns unique client IDs and Sales Value, but I would like to get just a list of IDs and have the IDs sorted by the sales value desc order.

```
`=unique(filter(Revenue_data!A1:B1000,Revenue_data!B6:B1000<>""))`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=unique(choosecols(sort(filter(Revenue_data!A2:B,Revenue_data!B2:B<>""),2,),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Building on @rockinfreakshow's answer, if you want the ID's ordered desc by the *total* sales value for a given ID you can try:

```
=CHOOSECOLS(
    QUERY(Revenue_data!A1:B,"
        SELECT A, sum(B) 
        WHERE B IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP BY A 
        ORDER BY sum(B) DESC"
    ,1)
,1)
```

*which returns ID `B` before `D` because B's total Sales Value of 170 is bigger than D's total Sales Value of 100.*

---

[image: query function example]

---